# ticks and text - facet_grid ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a group of time series with ggplot, to be printed on a B5 paper.

Are able to make this plot:

```
qplot(trade.date, value, data = meltreg2, geom='line', group = variable) + 
  facet_grid(variable ~ ., scale = 'free_y')  +
  scale_x_date(expand=c(0,0), name='') +
  opts(strip.text.y = theme_blank(), strip.background = theme_blank(), panel.background = 
    theme_rect(), panel.grid.major=theme_blank(), panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(), axis.title.x =
    theme_blank(), axis.title.y = theme_blank(), panel.margin = unit(0.5, 'line')
  )
```

but is there any way I can get ticks and text on all graphs (three graphs)?

and how should I save the plot to best suit a B5 (landscape) page?

---

I would like to have ticks and text on all x axis, not to hide them with theme_blank().
(the default for the plot above is only ticks and text on the graph that is plotted "last", but I need on all)

Comment: For the last question, you should be using an appropriate graphics device function , like pdf() or tiff(), and appropriate "special" settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is how to get ticks and text.  Well, by using `opts(...=theme_blank())` you are explicitly hiding text in your plot.  You can control the display of ticks and text in exactly this way.

Your second question is how to save the plot in a specific size.  To do this, your best option is to use `ggsave()`.  This function will save a `ggplot` in a variety of formats, and you can specify the height and width.  My favourite search engine tells me that B5 size is 6.93 × 9.84 inches:

```
ggsave(filename="trade.pdf", plot=last_plot(), width=9.84, height=6.93)
```